# add current video time with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can add frame number to video with ffmpeg as below:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -an -vf drawtext=fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{frame_num}':x=20:y=20 -f mp4 output.mp4
```

How can I modify it to show HH:MM:SS instead of current frame number?

Comment: use `pts:hms` instead of `frame_num` see [the doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kesh pointed out `pts:hms` instead of `frame_num` does the job but your specific command line, will lead you astray, as you have omitted a set of encapsulating quotes.
Whilst omitting them, works with `frame_num`, it will not work with `pts:hms`

Use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -an -vf "drawtext=fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:hms}':x=20:y=20" -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Here the entire `drawtext` filter is wrapped in quotation marks.
[image]

Edit:
To achieve pure `HH:MM:SS` format use `gmtime` rather than `hms` i.e.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -an -vf "drawtext=fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text=' %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%T}':x=20:y=20" -f mp4 output.mp4
```

[image]

Comment: Great,, it works now! Is it possible to show 1 digits only, now it show 3 digits.

Comment: @lucky1928 Not that I'm aware of. You can use a strftime() format string, if you use `gmtime` instead of `hms` e,g, `text=' %{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%T}'` but `strftime` doesn't appear to do milliseconds.